# mysql select 2 table based on date and combine each other

Tags: mysql, join

i Need some help.. i have some case like this below

i have 2 table.. call ("in_table" and "out_table")

data "in_table" look like

```
stock_id    item_id      date      qty_in  
-----------------------------------------
1             11          2017-07-11   12
2             11          2017-07-11   10
3             12          2017-07-11   10
4             12          2017-07-19   10
```

And i have "out_table" is like

```
id_tr   item_id     date        qty_out  
-------------------------------------
1           11       2017-07-19   2
1           12       2017-07-19   1
2           11       2017-07-19   2
2           12       2017-07-19   1
```

And i want to combine the date and display all the data like this,

Update: the join is by item_id but i want to select by date

```
date           item_id   qty_in   qty_out 
---------------------------------------
2013-07-11     11         22       0
2013-07-11     12         10       0
2013-07-19     11         0        4
2013-07-19     12         10       2
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can simply search for `MySQL JOIN` and do it by yourself

Comment: @Mojtaba look like union left and right join.. but the date has different column like (null and date) and i want to merge each other

Comment: in Stack Overflow, we do not provide codes from scratch. We help each other to improve the codes and fix the bugs. You have not put any codes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need kind of a full outer join of two aggregate subqueries. But in your case I would get `item_id` and `date` in a union subquery (derived table) and the sums in correlated subqueries (subselect).

```
select item_id, date,
    (select sum(qty_in)  from in_table  i where i.item_id = sub.item_id and i.date = sub.date) as qty_in,
    (select sum(qty_out) from out_table o where o.item_id = sub.item_id and o.date = sub.date) as qty_out
from (
    select item_id, date from in_table
    union
    select item_id, date from out_table
) sub
order by date, item_id
```